# How to define a different type variable in C++?

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code for example.

```
template <class T>
void g(T b){
  ;
}

template <class T>
void h(T b){
   ;
}

class T{
   method X;
   method Y;
   method Z; //many methods but the implementation of the methods are different from TT
};

class TT{
   method X;
   method Y;
   method Z; //the implementation of the methods are different from T
}
void f(){

  if(a==1){
  T b;  //use type T to define b
  } else{
  TT b; //use type TT to define b
  }

 g(b);
 h(b);
 i(b);// I need to use b for many different functions.
```

}

I also need the scope of variable b is in the function f.

In class T and TT, there are many methods but the implementation of the methods are different.

Any suggestions?

Comment: exactly like that

Comment: This is fine if you are only using `b` inside those `{}`. Otherwise, you can't (easily or cleanly) do it.

Comment: There are various troublesome ways of somehow doing what you ask, but generally the solution is to do something completely different. How about asking what you want from it and we could propose a better solution.

Comment: What do what to do with `b`? Are you just using `b` with in the `{}`?

Comment: Templates or polymorphism are your alternatives. But they're very big topics, you need to do some reading I think.

Comment: Please show how you intend to use `b`

Comment: if TT and T are unrelated types, how do you expect to use the objects after `if`? e.g. how do you plan to call methods on it, when they can have completely unrelated interface?

Comment: @Zdeslav Vojkovic they can still be used provided they implement the same **Concept**

Comment: @Zadirion, if by concept, you mean interface (as API, not base class) then yes, but that's why I say unrelated (and you can use templates anyway). If you means concept as a feature removed from standard, then it is not really C++.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic no, by concept I mean **Concept** as in **Container concept** for example. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: what was removed from the C++0x proposals was a feature to formalize (and inform the compiler about) something that was already called "concepts" in English before the language feature was invented to support it. So `Iterator`, `Allocator`, `Container` etc. are all still "concepts", regardless of the fact that there was a withdrawn proposal to add "concepts" to the standard :-)

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic more simply put, right now it is an unenforced (because of lack of language support) agreement between two parts that a certain type (template parameter) has certain members named in a certain way and having certain signatures.

Comment: @SteveJessop, of course, I am completely aware of that, but that's exactly why I explicitly ask about unrelated types: not just inheritance, but completely unrelated - I count types implementing the same concept as related, as that's what they really are.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic well, nobody said `T` and `TT` in OP's question are unrelated by your definition.

Comment: @Zadirion well, nobody said that e.g. TT doesn't derive from T, but still nobody suggested to use `T*` - I avoid assuming something which is not obvious and is not specified. The reason I ask is that without clarifying these assumptions it is not possible to make a good answer. E.g. your answer assumes concepts, otherwise you need to rely on explicit specialization

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic there are no assumptions in my answer, it directly addresses OP's question regardless of whether TT derives from T or not. The question would have made no sense if my assumption was incorrect. It is quite clear regardless of `b`'s type it can be used the same way. The question clearly states `b` will be pased to a function `g` regardless of `b`'s type. It is you who is incorrectly assuming OP doesn't know what he's doing.

Comment: without explicit specialization, you can't really use `b` in template function if you don't assume the concept (or inheritance, why didn't you assume that?). what method would you call that both `TT` and `T` satisfy it? Actually, I am afraid that question really doesn't make sense and that OP is not sure what he does, based on question edits and on his other question - that's why I voted to close it.

Comment: @Zdeslav, this is my second time to ask question here. I can improve my question by keeping editing it. I do not understand why you need to argue here to waste your time if you do not want to answer the question.

Comment: I don't try to argue and I am sorry if I came harsh on the other side - I wanted to urge you to explicitly state the assumptions (i.e. inheritance, same concept, whatever) in order to provide the answer, as correct answer will differ based on that. as you can see, comments by other members resulted in 6 edits to the question which is now much clearer than in the beginning and shows that you use same 'concept' so templates are proper solution. this is good thing

Answer (score 1):

Use [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) and move the code you had in `f()` that would use `b` inside `DoStuff()`.

```
template <class Type>
void DoStuff()
{
  Type b;  //use type 'Type' to define b      
}

void f(){

  if(a==1){
    DoStuff<T>();
  } else{
    DoStuff<TT>();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how about the scope of the variable b? I need to use it for the function f.

Comment: @user2145796 move the code you have in function `f` that uses `b` inside `DoStuff`.

Comment: Zadirion Thanks. I have so many other things to do with b inside f. Any other suggestions?

Comment: why wouldn't those things work in `DoStuff` if they work in `f`?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic this would be almost the same as use f as a template if I move all the functions f, g and h to DoStuff. I just use b very often but I do not want f to be a template of class T and TT. I am thinking about if there a way to use "typedef" for example, if(a==1) typedef T cos ; else typedef T sin; T b;

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If you want to use `b` in the rest of the function, then `TT` and `T` must expose the same interface. In that case you can use it in both functions equally (ignoring the fact that you can't use it in `f` at all as these are different types).

Comment: @user2145796 types are things determined at compile time. You can not decide at runtime which type to use for something. Not unless we are involving polymorphism in which case the Factory pattern is what you might need. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_object